# Docker link between varnish and wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, varnish

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

   varnish:
     image: eeacms/varnish
     depends_on:
       - wordpress
     ports:
       - 9000:6081
     environment:
       DNS_ENABLED: "true"
       BACKENDS: wordpress
       BACKENDS_PORT: 80
volumes:
    db_data:
```

**wordpress** is running on `0.0.0.0:8080` and on `172.17.0.1:8080`

But the **/etc/hosts** of varnish container is like this

```
root@4cc3dc214d69:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  wordpress fd3f01c29d6a dockoor_wordpress_1
172.17.0.3  wordpress_1 fd3f01c29d6a dockoor_wordpress_1
172.17.0.3  dockoor_wordpress_1 fd3f01c29d6a
172.17.0.4  4cc3dc214d69
```

varnish is mapping **wordpress** to **172.17.0.3**
That why while trying to access `0.0.0.0:8000` i get

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Backend fetch failed
Guru Meditation:

XID: 3

Varnish cache server
```

Can someone please point out whats wrong with my compose file?

P.S docker-compose log shows that varnish do hit worpress but its getting a 302 response.

```
02 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 338 "-" "-"
wordpress_1     | 172.17.0.4 - - [25/Mar/2017:10:45:39 +0000] "G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link appears to be working as expected. 0.0.0.0 is not an IP address you connect to, that's a listener IP that tells the networking stack to listen on all interfaces rather than a specific IP on the host. In your case, all IP's includes 127.0.0.1 (loopback inside the container) and 172.17.0.3 (the IP reachable by other containers on that network.

Note that links are largely deprecated, it's preferred to configure the containers on a network (other than the default bridge) and use the built in DNS discovery. Similarly, compose version 1 file formats are also largely deprecated, you should consider upgrading to at least the version 2 compose file format. With that format, a network will be created by default for your containers to communicate.

Here's an example of your compose file in version 2 format:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass

  varnish:
    image: eeacms/varnish
    ports:
    - "8000:6081"
    environment:
      DNS_ENABLED: "true"
      BACKENDS: "wordpress"
      BACKENDS_PORT: 8080
```

The http 302 is a redirect, whatever you are running is able to see the url but isn't following the redirect or wordpress is not configured to give a correct redirect.

---

Update: The varnish error you are seeing is because you are probing / on the wordpress server which is responding with a 302 redirect. Varnish appears to need a 200 success code for the url it is probing. For that, you can add a variable like the following to your varnish environment:

```
BACKENDS_PROBE_URL: /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
```

Comment: Changed the compose file. Still the same behavior.